# convert ushort to long in 64 bit architecture in c++

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit

I am porting code from 32bit UNIX to 64 bit LINUX machine.

If I have a variable in `const long say l1` and a variable in `ushort` say `us1`. Now I need to compare these two say `if( l1 != us1)` .... this is not working. What typecasting should I use?

This piece worked in 32 bit Unix but works unpredictably in Linux 64 bit. Sometimes it works correctly and sometimes doesn't.

The reason is number of bits occupied by long is changed now. I am planning to convert `us1` (which is a `ushort`) to `ulong` and then compare. say `(l1 != (ulong) us1)`. But again in this `l1` will still be signed.

Please suggest what should be appropriate type conversions. Code snippet is below:

```
nise::facex::order::NiseWorkOrder *wrkOrd = 0;  (this is a USHORT)  
int retCode = getNiseOrder(wrkOrd, asyncQ->m_order_number);
```

`NiseWorkOrder` is a function where `wrkOrd` is a reference to pointer.
`getniseorder` does a CROBA call and populate `NiseWorkOrder` structure.

Now, `asyncQ->m_version_num` is an `osplong`.

```
TRACEPRT(APP_LVL, ("wrkOrd->orderHead.wrkOrdKey.order.orderVersion = <%d>",wrkOrd->orderHead.wrkOrdKey.order.orderVersion));  
TRACEPRT(APP_LVL, ("(const long)asyncQ->m_version_num = <%d>", (const long)asyncQ->m_version_num));  
(const long)asyncQ->m_version_num !=
             wrkOrd->orderHead.wrkOrdKey.order.orderVersion)  
......
```

The issue is that although traces always show both values as same still sometimes if condition is true(which should not be.

Comment: It would help if you provided actual code that illustrates your problem.  There are several possible explanations for your problem, depending on what ranges a `long` and a `ushort` can represent on the target system, what values **l1** and **us1** hold, etc.  And therefore multiple possible fixes.   Your description **const long say l1** doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @Peter As I told the target system is a 64 bit machine. Hence long wil  be 64 bit and ushort will be 16 bit. Actuall code is following:  CORBA::ushort ord = <something via CORBA call>  if(const long(x) != ord) ...  Here x is a long osp (db) variable. So basically I am comparing a CORBA::USHORT and a const long variable.

Comment: The problem is likely something entirely different from what you diagnosed.  You seem to believe comparing a 32 bit signed number to a 16 bit unsigned number behaved correctly, but comparing a 64 bit signed to 16 bit unsigned doesn't do the same.  No cast is needed nor helpful to get the 64bit signed to 16bit unsigned comparison to act exactly the same as the original 32bit signed to 16bit unsigned.  Whatever the actual cause of your problem/symptom might be, it is elsewhere.

Comment: No, Shefali.   Your question gave no basis to assume a long is 64 bit and short is 16 bit - there is nothing which guarantees that, even on a 64 bit system.  Even now you've revealed that your code uses CORBA types, you haven't given enough info (e.g. there is actually no guarantee that a `CORBA::UShort` variable is exactly 16 bits).   As I said, give actual code.  Also describe what compiler you're using, what build options, what ORB, etc.   Basic rule though:  if you don't know what the problem is, you are not qualified to decide what is relevant or what is not.

Comment: @Peter  I have updated my post and provided code snippet

Comment: If you put as much precision in your source code as you do while creating your posts then you're going to have big problems.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I didn't understand. Please elaborate what you mean.

Comment: I quickly went through your questions when you were welcomed by another user. I sometimes do that so I can help them ask better questions. This one I had to edit if just to get to understand it myself. It still reads CROBA - probably instead of CORBA. Not capitalizing sentences, starting sentences too early, not highlighting code properly, etc. all make the question hard to read and look unprofessional. I'm just hoping that you don't do the same with the code you're writing, because somebody is going to be in trouble if you do - most likely a future you if you stay in place.

Comment: I've called myself names multiple times after reviewing bad code written by some incompetent programmer that turned out to be me :) Probably best not to have the same feeling when re-reading the questions you asked on an online Q/A site.